# How to setup stage-specific microprofile config with java-ee8, microProfile 4.0, Openliberty 21 and Docker

Tags: java, docker, open-liberty, microprofile, eclipse-microprofile-config

I have a problem with my application using JavaEE8, Openliberty 21.0.0.5 and Microprofile 4.0 inside a docker container.
I cannot set the mpConfig-2.0-introduced `mp.config.profile` from "outside" the image.
My setup is as follows:

```
microprofile-config.properties
microprofile-config-dev.properties
microprofile-config-prod.properties
```

inside `src/main/resources/META-INF/`

Features are correctly activated inside server.xml and are installed correctly on startup.

```
<featureManager onError="WARN">
    <feature>microProfile-4.0</feature>
    <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

I also have one server.env per stage that is passed to my container via docker run's `--env-file`.

My first approach was to set `mp.config.profile` inside the `server.env` since it can be
changed when running the image on different stages.
f.e. `mp.config.profile=dev` inside `server-dev.env` an so forth.
However the values of microprofile-config-dev.properties are never used with this setup.

The only way I was able to correctly activate the config profile was when using

```
<variable name="mp.config.profile" value="dev" />
```

inside the `server.xml`.

However the `server.xml` is not stage-specific inside the docker image, so it won't be possible to change it on different stages.

Does anyone have a suggestions what is the correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set `mp.config.profile` from `server.env`, you probably need to set `MP_CONFIG_PROFILE` instead.

Since dots aren't valid in environment variable names, MP Config [defines some mapping rules](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-config-2.0/microprofile-config-spec-2.0.html#default_configsources.env.mapping) when looking up config from environment variables. It will check for the requested name with non-alphanumeric characters converted to underscores, and then again also with all letters converted to uppercase.

Comment: I was pretty sure that I already tried both lowercase and uppercase with underscores but apparently I had some other misconfiguration when I tried that.
Anyways, it works now. Thanks!